# Android - How to handle a web request which is redirected

Tags: php, android, api, redirect, httpwebrequest

I have an API which handles get + post requests however I've had reports of a bug whereby users who are connected behind a corporate network are not able to authenticate within my app.

Basically what happens is the user sends a post requst (username + password) to an api and the API responds with a json result

However the network is shaping the traffic such that the initial request is redirected via a web server and responds with a html message like this;

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Web Authentication Redirect</TITLE><META http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><META http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"><META http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=https://wirelessauth.login.html?redirect=bla.co.uk/android/api/auth">
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

This would normally redirect a browser to the correct page however within my android app I don't know how I can handle this?

This is probably as clear as mud but thanks for your help :)

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution would be to negotiate an exception to the redirect with your network administrator, but here is something you can try to hack your way around it:

- Make the http post, and if you don't get one of your expected errors or responses, try loading the response in a WebView with [loadDataWithBaseUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (do not use loadData, it is broken!) and let the webview handle the redirect.  The webview does not have to be visible to do the work for you.  Use the webview callbacks to intercept any responses or pages that come back after the redirect and parse/deal with them as appropriate outside of the webview.

Answer (score 0):

either your wireless connection on your device is not authenticated or internet service provider isn't working. Try browsing the web and try again.